How to split the full name column into first, middle and last name columns in SQL redshift
We got a requirement in the redshift table to split the full name column into first_name, middle_name, last_name columns with the help of space in the string using the SQL script. Below is the sample data and expected output for the columns. The first_name and last_name are deriving fine but getting issues for the middle_namewe with the below SQL, it removes the strings in middle name which is the common in other two columns hence it is not working for a few scenarios below are examples
Can you please help us fix this issue?

SQL Query: "Select fullname ,
SUBSTRING(fullname , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname) - 1) as FirstName,
RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(fullname,SUBSTRING(fullname , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname) - 1),''),
REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(fullname), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(fullname))-1 ) ),'')))as MiddleName,
REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(fullname), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(fullname))-1 ) ) as LastName
From (select 'john johnson' fullname)"





Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I'd use REGEXP_SUBSTR for this. In my opinion this gets this whole thing more readable:
select
  fullname,
  regexp_substr(full_name, '^[^ ]+') as first_name,
  trim(' ' from regexp_substr(full_name, ' .* ')) as middle_name,
  regexp_substr(full_name, '[^ ]+$') as last_name
from mytable;

Explanation of the regular expressions:

'^[^ ]+' = non-blank characters directly after string start
' .* ' = first blank and last blank and all characters inbetween
'^[^ ]+' = non-blank characters directly before string end

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRIM.html

There is a small issue with single-name splits into first and last-name columns
Below is an example

That is correct. For a single name like 'Wallace' my script will have it both as first and last name. As Wallace is a valid first name as well as a valid last name, the question arises: Do you consider a single word name a first name or a last name?

Yes, the single word name should be the first name.

Then include the blank when looking for the last name: trim(' ' from regexp_substr(full_name, ' [^ ]+$')) as last_name.
